# Why is my call to getInputStream() returning an empty html string?

Tags: php, android, json, post

Wondering what the hell is going on and desperately need help.

Am trying to return some JSON from the server and get this instead...
`<!doctype html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8><title>Untitled Document</title></head><body></body></html>`

So... my code.

Android code:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        try {
            data.put("showTips", "true"); 
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Headers
        ArrayList<String[]> headers = new ArrayList<>();

        headers.add(new String[]{"custom-header", "custom value"});
        headers.add(new String[]{"Content-Type", "application/json"});
        try{
            URL url = new URL("https://www.grinners4winners.com.au/grin1_app_backend/post2.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++) {
                conn.setRequestProperty(headers.get(i)[0], headers.get(i)[1]);
            }
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(data));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

            int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
            String responseMessage=conn.getResponseMessage();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("status_code", responseCode);
            jsonObject.put("status_message", responseMessage);

            if (jsonObject.getInt("status_code")< 400) {
                // BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResult.getResponse()));
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

                String result = "";

                while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += inputLine;
                }
                in.close();

                return result;
            }else{
                return "false: ".concat(String.valueOf(responseCode));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "Exception: ".concat(e.getMessage());
        }
```

For testing purposes I've tired to scale back the PHP to the bare necessities removing a bunch of other code and additional $_POST checks and still no luck. 
Here's the PHP

```
<?php
ob_start();
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8'); 
header ('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
header("Expires: Sun, 16 Jul 2017 05:00:00 GMT");
//if ($_POST['showTips']){
$json = json_encode(file_get_contents('./tips.json'));
if ($json===false){
    $json = json_encode(array("jsonError",json_last_error_msg()));
    if ($json ===false){
        $json='{"jsonError":"unknown"}';
    }
    http_response_code(500);
}
echo $json;
//}
```

ob_end_flush();
?>

If I punch in the URL in my browser, it echos the contents of tips.json as I'd expect (validated this at JSONLint). Basically, I've got no clue as to what's going on. Cheers for any suggestions.

Comment: "If I punch in the URL in my browser" -- if you mean via the address bar, that would result in a GET request, not a POST.

Comment: True, just included that to show that it's not experiencing any issues in retrieving the file. So.. why can't it do that with POST?

Comment: Still no progress, x fingers tomorrow sheds some light

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled across a brilliant tool (PostMan, ttps://www.getpostman.com/)  which massively simplified my Java code. It spat out the following code...

```
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "showTips=test");
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://www.grinners4winners.com.au/grn1_app_backend/post2.php")
                .post(body)
                .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
                .addHeader("postman-token", "a8529ea3-b9af-38ed-f9cc-322e3e9971e3")
                .build();
```

All I had to do then was just hook into the response as follows. Really simple.

```
        String returnvar = "";
        ResponseBody rb;
        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            rb = response.body();
            returnvar = rb.string();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return returnvar;
```